how to close dialog box based on state loading
In this  code i had shown dialog box in 2 ways:

In post method
2.another in login button onpressed
by using setstate either true or false .

Now, while status code = 200 , dialog box opens and closes on success . but if other error occurs; for eg: if id password missmatch , snackbar shows error message but dialog box does not close . What changes should i make in below code and any other easy ways to implement dialog box till it process post method .(i am trying to show progess/loading indicator).
It should closes automatically when method completes , by user not tapping anywhere
//imports

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
 //other intilizations
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
  }


  Future<void> postUser() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) return;
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    showAlertDialog(context);
    final encodedUser = Uri.encodeComponent(_usernameController.text);
    final encodedPassword = Uri.encodeComponent(_passwordController.text);
    var url = Uri.parse(
      '${Config.baseUrl}/token',
    );
    var bodyData = {
      'username': encodedUser,
      'password': encodedPassword,
      'grant_type': "password"
    };
    try {
      final response = await http.post(url, body: bodyData);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
        if (responseBody.containsKey('access_token')) {
          Token user = Token.fromJson(responseBody);
          if (user.accessToken.isNotEmpty) {
            await _storeToken(user.accessToken);
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/Home');
          } else {
            _showSnackBar('Authentication failed. Please try again.');
          }
        } else {
          _showSnackBar('Authentication failed. No access token received.');
        }
      } else if (response.statusCode == 400) {
        _showSnackBar('Credentials did not match !: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      _showSnackBar(
          'No internet connection. Please check your connection and try again.');
    } on HttpException catch (_) {
      _showSnackBar('Could not connect to the server. Please try again later.');
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      print('Exception occurred: $e');
      print('Stack trace: $stackTrace');
      _showSnackBar('An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.');
    } finally {}
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

 //other methods

  void _showSnackBar(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(
          message,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Center(child: Text('Logging In')),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 0, horizontal: screenWidth * 0.27),
              child: ListBody(
                children: const <Widget>[
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Config.backgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [

            //other ui
              ),
              //form
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.03),
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
         
                    // form fields to enter id and password
                    
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.032 * screenHeight),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                             setState(() {
                              isLoading = true;
                         });
                            showAlertDialog(context);
                            postUser();
                             setState(() {
                               isLoading = false;
                            });
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            backgroundColor: Config.themeMainColor,
                            shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                            fixedSize: Size(
                              screenWidth * 0.5,
                              screenHeight * 0.01,
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            'Login',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Config.backgroundColor,
                                fontSize: 16 * (screenWidth / 360)),
//other parts        
}


I tried to show loading indicator when isLoading==true and closes itself when isloading==false either post method success or fail

You can use flutter_portal to show dialogs declaratively
